rvest - error 403 from computer A but not computer B (same network)
Until few weeks ago, I was able to periodically run a script to scrape https://unjobs.org from my Lubuntu 20.04 machine.
Ever since I installed a fresh 24.04 from scratch, rvest gives me a 403 when running the same script.
library(rvest)
read_html('https://unjobs.org')
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403.

i also tried using 'polite', using a different user agent in line with robots.txt:
library(polite)
scrape(bow('https://unjobs.org', user_agent='Twitterbot'))
NULL
Warning message:
Client error: (403) Forbidden https://unjobs.org

I tried running the script from another Windows machine, and from there the script runs like a charm. i have the same setup on both machines
R 4.4.0
rvest 1.0.4
httr 1.4.7
Any guesses where the issue is?
Tnx

The likely answer is that the site has shut down scrappers
library(rvest)
library(polite)

url <- "https://unjobs.org"

bow(url, user_agent = "This is not scrappable")
#> <polite session> https://unjobs.org
#>     User-agent: This is not scrappable
#>     robots.txt: 12 rules are defined for 6 bots
#>    Crawl delay: 5 sec
#>   The path is not scrapable for this user-agent

Created on 2024-06-17 with reprex v2.1.0

That's what I thought too, but:

I can run the script from my windows machine (without even setting a user agent) connected to the same router
I ran the script from my previous Lubuntu 20.04 installation just few hours before

The only thing I can think of is that the website doesn't like my new Lubuntu installation, but - aside from user_agent - what information do httr and rvest share with the website when scraping?
